# Aligning Dataframes based on count on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am aligning two dataframes which look like the following:

1. Dataframe 1

   ```
   Timestamp  L_x   L_y    L_a     R_x     R_y     R_a
   2403950   621.3 461.3   313     623.3   461.8   260
   2404050   622.5 461.3   312     623.3   462.6   260
   2404150   623.1 461.5   311     623.4   464     261
   2404250   623.6 461.7   310     623.7   465.4   261
   2404350   623.8 461.5   309     623.9   466.1   261
   ```
2. Dataframe 2

This dataframe contains the timestamps that a particular event occured.

```
  Timestamp
0  2404030
1  2404050
2  2404250
3  2404266
4  2404282
5  2404298
6  2404314
7  2404330
8  2404350
9  2404382
```

All timestamps are in milliseconds. As you can see, the first dataframe is resampled to 100milliseconds. So what I want to do is, to align the two dataframes based on count. Which means based on the count how many events occur during a particular 100milliseconds bin time. For example, from the dataframe 1, in the first 100millisecond bin time (24043950 - 2404049), only one event occur according to the second dataframe which is at 2404030 and so on. The aligned table should look like the following:

```
 Timestamp  L_x   L_y    L_a     R_x     R_y     R_a    count
  2403950   621.3 461.3   313     623.3   461.8   260    1
  2404050   622.5 461.3   312     623.3   462.6   260    1
  2404150   623.1 461.5   311     623.4   464     261    0
  2404250   623.6 461.7   310     623.7   465.4   261    6
  2404350   623.8 461.5   309     623.9   466.1   261    2
```

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to perform integer division on the timestamp (i.e. `a // b`), but first need to add 50 to it given your bucketing.  Then convert it back into the correct units by multiplying by 100 and subtracting 50.

Now, group on this new index and perform a count.

You then merge these counts to your original dataframe and do some formatting operations to get the data in the desired shape.  Make sure to fill NaNs with zero.

```
df2['idx'] = (df2.Timestamp + 50) // 100 * 100 - 50

counts = df2.groupby('idx').count()

>>> counts
         Timestamp
idx               
2403950          1
2404050          1
2404250          6
2404350          2

df_new =df.merge(counts, how='left', left_on='Timestamp', right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_'])
columns = list(df_new)
columns[-1] = 'count'
df_new.columns = columns
df_new['count'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

>>> df_new
   Timestamp    L_x    L_y  L_a    R_x    R_y  R_a  count
0    2403950  621.3  461.3  313  623.3  461.8  260      1
1    2404050  622.5  461.3  312  623.3  462.6  260      1
2    2404150  623.1  461.5  311  623.4  464.0  261      0
3    2404250  623.6  461.7  310  623.7  465.4  261      6
4    2404350  623.8  461.5  309  623.9  466.1  261      2
```

Comment: Or just `df2.groupby([df2.Timestamp.map(lambda x: (x+50) // 100 * 100 - 50)]).count()`

Comment: @Alexander: By df, do you mean dataframe 1?

Comment: Yes, I mean dataframe1